# SQL Server Select orders which have all of a set of items

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, relational-division

I have the following tables, Order and OrderLine:

```
Order:

 id | total
 ----------
  1 | 55.09
  2 | 62.42

OrderLine:

 order_id | line_number | item      | qty
 ----------------------------------------
  1       | 1           | Product A | 50
  1       | 2           | Product B | 15
  2       | 1           | Product A | 23
```

I am looking to construct a query that will select all Orders which contain both Product A and Product B.

Some caveats:

1. There may be multiple lines that have Product A and Product B. For instance, there could be a third line in the `order 1` that has `Product A`
2. There can also be situations with many items that need to be requested, not just 2 as it in this case.
3. I am also looking to query by total quantity. So, for example, only orders which have more than 20 units of Product A in total (across all lines).

My first thought was do an inner join per item, so something like:

```
SELECT
    T0.id
FROM
    Order T0
    INNER JOIN OrderLine T1 on T1.order_id = T0.id AND T1.ItemCode = 'Product A'
    INNER JOIN OrderLine T2 on T1.order_id = T0.id AND T2.ItemCode = 'Product B'
GROUP BY
    T0.id
```

However, I'm not sure how to extend this to have the ability to select based on total quantity. Possibly using SUM and HAVING?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a typical example of [Relational Division With Remainder](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/),** where the number of divisors is unknown.

There are a number of ways to cut this, but fundamentally, the key to solving this neatly is to put your input data into tabular form. This could be a temp table, table variable or Table Valued Parameter.

Here is one typical Relational Division solution. Note that the `OUTER APPLY` could also be done with a grouped `LEFT JOIN`.

```sql
DECLARE @input TABLE (item varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY, quantity int);
INSERT @input VALUES
('Product A',20),('Product B',NULL);

SELECT
  o.id
FROM Order_tbl o 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM @input i
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT ol.item
        FROM OrderLine ol
        WHERE ol.item = i.item AND o.id = ol.order_id
        GROUP BY
          ol.item
        HAVING SUM(ol.qty) > i.quantity OR i.quantity IS NULL
    ) ol
    HAVING COUNT(ol.item) = COUNT(*)
);
```

---

Another method is a double `NOT EXISTS` although this is commonly not efficient.

```sql
SELECT
  o.id
FROM Order_tbl o 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM @input i
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM OrderLine ol
        WHERE ol.item = i.item AND o.id = ol.order_id
        GROUP BY
          ol.item
        HAVING SUM(ol.qty) > i.quantity OR i.quantity IS NULL
    )
);
```

---

A final option, which is partially used by one of the other answers, is to pre-calculate the count of input values, and then use a normal join. This is often the most efficient.

Again the `INNER JOIN` could be a `CROSS APPLY`.

```sql
DECLARE @count int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @input);

SELECT
  o.id
FROM Order_tbl o 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM (
        SELECT
          ol.item,
          ol.order_id,
          SUM(ol.qty) totalQty
        FROM OrderLine ol
        GROUP BY
          ol.item,
          ol.order_id
    ) ol
    JOIN @input i ON ol.item = i.item AND o.id = ol.order_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN ol.totalQty > i.quantity OR i.quantity IS NULL THEN 1 END)
       AND COUNT(*) = @count
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1b38f2ea9ff1cbfb5dce42fac9382407)

Answer (score 0):

You can use having count with sum.

Try:

```
select o.id,o.total
from Order_tbl o 
inner join ( select order_id
             from OrderLine
             where item in ('Product A','Product B')
             group by order_id
             having count(distinct item)=2  and  sum(case when item = 'Product A' then qty end ) > 20
            ) as ol on o.id=ol.order_id;
```

`having count(distinct item)=2`  will select only the order_id which have both Product A and Product B  values. If you would add new products , include the new one on the where condition and increase 2 with the total number of products  .

`sum(case when item = 'Product A' then qty end ) > 20` will return only the records where total SUM of Product A > 20

Testing [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=25fa398332931e557b0ec7a173b51281)

Answer (score 0):

use a `GROUP BY` query and place the required condition in the `HAVING` clause

Condition : *Orders which contain both Product A and Product B*

```
having sum(case when l.item = 'Product A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and    sum(case when l.item = 'Product B' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Condition : *Orders which have more than 20 units of Product A in total (across all lines).*

```
sum(case when l.item = 'Product A' then qty else 0 end) >= 20
```

Query:

```
select o.id
from   [Order] o
       inner join [OrderLine] l on o.id = l.order_id
group by o.id
having sum(case when l.item = 'Product A' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and    sum(case when l.item = 'Product B' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and    sum(case when l.item = 'Product A' then qty else 0 end) >= 20
```